# MS Access Report can't enter text in unbound textboxes

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-reports

I have a report in MS Access 2016 where the `Record Source` is set to a query I created.

I have bound textboxes to display the data from the query correctly.

The issue comes when I'm trying to use unbound textboxes. I have an unbound textbox where I would like to enter a custom value, say the name. When I type in the textbox, the text appears correctly. Once the focus leaves the textbox however, the text disappears.

Why is this happening and how do I make it so that the text will stay until I close/reset the report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike forms, reports are not meant to be interactive. Some limited interaction is possible in ReportView (button click, right click filter menu) and in PrintPreview can use right click menu for export options.

Enter text into unbound textbox on form. Have expression in report textbox ControlSource reference textbox on form.

`=Forms!formname.textboxname`

Then open report.

Or could pass data with OpenArgs argument of OpenReport (or OpenForm) referencing form textbox.
`DoCmd.OpenReport "reportname", acViewPreview, , , , Me.textbox`
Then expression in report textbox can pull value from OpenArgs property.
`=[OpenArgs]`

Either way, input is via control on form.

Another approach is a popup input in query used as report RecordSource.
`SELECT table.*, [enter name] AS F1 FROM table;`
Bind textbox to field F1.
When report opens, popup will appear for input and this input will display in textbox.

Comment: Okay good to know. It's unfortunate that you can't add temporary values in the report itself. The solution where you reference the form field itself within the textbox `ControlSource` works for me though. Thanks